# Imagecache custom action: scale image to width defined by other field

Tags: media

I would like to define a custom image style with [imagecache_actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) module, where the image is scaled to a width (in pixels) given by a interger field in the same node. How is this accomplished?

Comment: Any reason you want to use imagecache for this purpose? How about creating another image field on the same node. You can resize the image from one field and save into another field by [image_resize()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!image.inc/function/image_resize/7.x). Is it more make sense to you?

Comment: This approach sounds promising, thank you! I'll do some research, in case I can't find enough information, I'll open a new question for that approach.

Comment: I now posted a follow-up question here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208686/resizing-image-from-one-field-and-save-result-in-another-field/208687#208687 would be glad if you show up there!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a custom module to do this. Something like this... Create two files in a folder, for example, we'll call this User Defined Width.

**user_defined_width.info**

```
name = User Defined Width
description = A module that allows a user to define an image width.
core = 7.x
```

**user_defined_width.module**

```
<?php

function user_defined_width_image_effect_info(){
  $effects=array();
  $effects['advance_resize']=array(
    'label'=>t('User Defined Width'),
    'help'=>t('Resize to a size defined by the user.'),
    'effect callback'=>'user_defined_width_effect',
    'dimensions callback' => 'image_resize_dimensions',
    'form callback' => 'image_resize_form',
    'summary theme' => 'image_resize_summary',
  );
  return $effects;
}

function user_defined_width_effect(stdClass $image, $width, $height) {
      // Your logic here.

  $image->resource = YOUR_IMAGE;
  $image->info['width'] = YOUR_WIDTH_FIELD;
  $image->info['height'] = YOUR_HEIGHT_FIELD;
  return TRUE;
}
```

This should get you started, but the more I think about it, the more I think you are going to run into all sorts of problems with image caching, as image styles are stored in sites/default/files. You will need to override this some how and make sure the file regenerate on every page load. This wont be good for performance, but could probably be achieved with something like [Image Style Flush](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagestyleflush)

Comment: Thnak you, you are right with your concerns about performance, I didn't take that into account. The comment by Jimmy Ko, that suggests saving the modified image in a new field on the same node looks promising.