# Resizing image from one field and save result in another field

Tags: entities, media

As mentioned on the comments on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208585/imagecache-custom-action-scale-image-to-width-defined-by-other-field), on my node-editing-form there are fields for WIDTH, HEIGHT, and an IMAGE. I would like to resize the given image by the dimesions WIDTH and HEIGHT and to save the result in another image field. I hope someone could outline (or even concretise) how to build that module.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen [Imagefield Focus](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_focus)?

This would give your users a much nicer UI to edit and crop images, and more importantly choose the correct regions to crop.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what i am looking for. Toi better understand the context I edited my question because the link to another, related question was missing. What I am looking for is indeed how to save the results from one field to another.